# After reading an integer, and showing corresponding month, i can't read a string value, to show corresponding value of month

Tags: java, string, eclipse

I am new to Java and I have a code to write, but I ran into a problem. The task says:
*Write a Java application that reads an int value. If the int value is between 1-12, the corresponding string month will be displayed. Consider if the value entered is a string and if it corresponds to a month of the year, display the numeric value of the month.*
I wrote the code until it displays the corresponding month to the read value, but I don't know how to read a string if I declared an integer as a variable which is read from the keyboard. Here's the code:

````
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int num;
        System.out.println("Enter a number between 1-12: ");
        Scanner Obj= new Scanner(System.in);
        num=Obj.nextInt();

        switch(num)
        {
        case 1: 
            System.out.println("Month nr.1 is January");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Month nr.2 is February");
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("Month nr.3 is March");
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("Month nr.4 is April");
            break;
        case 5:
            System.out.println("Month nr.5 is May");
            break;
        case 6:
            System.out.println("Month nr.6 is June");
            break;
        case 7:
            System.out.println("Month nr.7 is July");
            break;
        case 8:
            System.out.println("Month nr.8 is August");
            break;
        case 9:
            System.out.println("Month nr.9 is September");
            break;
        case 10:
            System.out.println("Month nr.10 is October");
            break;
        case 11: 
            System.out.println("Month nr.11 is November");
            break;
        case 12:
            System.out.println("Month nr.12 is December");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("You entered an invalid number!");
        }
        
        Obj.close();

    }
    

} ```
* I'm using Eclipse with Java SE11. *
I need some clues how could I read a string as well, to show the corresponding value of month. Thanks!
````

Answer (score 2):

Instead of declaring an `int` to read the input declare a `String`.

```java
String input = scanner.nextLine();
try {
    int month = Integer.parseInt(input);
    showMonthName(month);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // If the input is not a number then exception would be thrown.
    showMonthNumber(input);
}
```